# How did Mars lose all its surface water?

Tags: water, atmospheric-science, planets, geophysics

A lot of geological evidence suggests that Mars once had quite a bit of surface water. I assume it wasn't whisked away into space, so where did it all go? What processes caused the water to go there?

Could the same happen on Earth, eventually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Water on Mars and Earth](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13366/887) (on [earthscience.se]).

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field of Mars is too week to protect its atmosphere from [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind). The solar wind can strip off Martian atmosphere. [This](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-mission-reveals-speed-of-solar-wind-stripping-martian-atmosphere/) was discovered by NASA.